# (JSON file)Is there any function to action in Wamp to make it work properly?

Tags: php, android, mysql, stickyrecycleview

Here is my **php** file to retrieve users informations using `recycleview` in android.
but it does not work I don't know. I need some help
 Here, image is TEXT and `String`, the others are varchar `String` also in my database 'xxxxx' table---users

```
    <?php
include("connect.php");

if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT nom, prenom, telephone, email,ncni, datenaissance, image FROM users ORDER BY id DESC ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);


 }

} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: i try to run on my localhost : http://localhost/myfoldername/users_list.php , it does not work .i am tired i worked all the night.

Comment: It's write something to output?

Comment: Do you just get the last row?

Comment: no i did not get the last row, i need to output all informations about users suscription in json format on my browser

Comment: i added some users in my table but can't retrieve them in json

Comment: row with '$result->num_rows' shoudln't be mysqli_num_rows($result) ? or $result-> rowCount() in case of PDO

Comment: i dont use PDO. i use : (mysqli_connect ) including variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a lot of mistakes in your code. You have skipped **mysqli** *(**query,fetch_assoc,num_rows** should be **mysqli_query,mysqli_fetch_assoc,mysqli_num_rows**)* everywhere. If you don't want to write mysqli multiple times, you should try PDO.
Here is an example:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8',DBUSER, DBPASS);
    //echo "Connected";
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    //print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    echo "Not Connected";
    die();
}


$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `nom`, `prenom`, `telephone`, `email`,`ncni`, `datenaissance`, `image` FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$query->execute();


if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    $data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($data);

}

else
{
   echo 'No Result Found';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much  and long life to you bro ! it worked .